# Batch replace text inside text file (Linux/OSX Commandline)

Tags: unix, command-line, replace, text-files, batch-processing

I have hundreds of files where I need to change a portion of its text.

For example, I want to replace every instance of "http://" with "rtmp://" .

The files have the .txt extention and are spread across several folders and subfolder.

I basically am looking for a way/script that goes trough every single folder/subfolder and every single file and if it finds inside that file the occurrence of "http" to replace it with "rtmp".

Answer (score 13):

You can do this with a combination of `find` and `sed`:

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -exec sed -i.bak 's|http://|rtmp://|g' {} +
```

This will create backups of each file. I suggest you check a few to make sure it did what you want, then you can delete them using

```
find . -name \*.bak -delete
```

Comment: Thank for the quick answer! However, how do I restrict the command to only .txt files? Because I do have other files in the folders, jpgs and such.

Comment: @user1596553 Alter Kevin's script to `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i.bak 's|http://|rtmp://|g' {} +`

Comment: Thank you both! I get the error

find: -exec CMD must end by ';'

but where exactly shall I put the ";"?

Comment: Kevin,
I was able to modify the line and bend it to my will. You just saved me hours of work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `zsh` function I use to do this:

```
change () {
        from=$1 
        shift
        to=$1 
        shift
        for file in $*
        do
                perl -i.bak -p -e "s{$from}{$to}g;" $file
                echo "Changing $from to $to in $file"
        done
}
```

It makes use of the nice Perl mechanism to create a backup file and modify the nominated file. You can use the above to iterate through files thus:

```
zsh$ change http:// rtmp:// **/*.html
```

or just put it in a trivial `#!/bin/zsh` script (I just use zsh for the powerful globbing)