# Batch modify text files

Tags: regex, markdown, batch-processing

I have a million markdown files spread across several sub-directories files with different titles where I want to change:

`# A Markdown title`

to

```
---
title: "A Markdown title"
---
```

…while keeping the rest of the file intact. Any ideas? OS X solutions prefered.

Comment: Are they all of the same structure? As in: `# Another title` should be converted to `title: "Another title"`?

Comment: All of them have different titles but it's always on one line.

Comment: If you are on Linux, this is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed -i 's/^# \(.*\)$/---\ntitle: \"\1\"\n---/' *`. The `*` means apply to all files in the current directory.

Alternatively search for files using Unix `find`. An example usage:

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" -exec sed 's/^# \(.*\)$/---\ntitle: \"\1\"\n---/' "{}" > "{}.bak" \; -exec mv "{}.bak" "{}" \;
```

This looks for all files with a java extension (in this directory and sub directories) and performs the substitution. It first stores the content in a file with a .bak extension and later moves it to the original file.

You can adjust the depth to search for the files using `find`'s `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` options.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm seeing --> $ sed -i 's/^# \(.*\)$/---\ntitle: \"\1\"\n---/' *
sed: 1: "test.md": undefined label 'est.md'   < -- ideas?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Mac has no -i option, you have to specify a different output file. This can be avoided though. What files are you trying to alter? i.e. do they have the same extension or anything else in common?

Comment: Yes, I'm on OS X. All files are .md, have several markdown titles and varying text. But only one "# title" (h1) each. Tried your 'find' example but it concats all files into one {}.bak file and titles become: '---ntitle: "JavaScript"n---' (doesn't respect new lines). Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: So, I installed `brew install gnu-sed` and ran `gsed -i.backup -e 's/^# \(.*\)$/---\ntitle: \"\1\"\n---/g' *.md` which seems to work. Apparently the default sed verison on OS X doesn't like new lines.

Comment: Nice, glad to see it work now! Don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved! If you want to do more stuff like this it's definitely advisable to look into GNU awk too, another powerful command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

In windows: Use the notepad++ "find in files" option. It searches through all files in a (set of) directories and replaces text. Regular expressions are supported.

On mac: use the build in "find" command line tool. Here's more info: [Batch replace text inside text file (Linux/OSX Commandline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364514/batch-replace-text-inside-text-file-linux-osx-commandline)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are all in one folder and that the title is on the first line a python script to do this would look like this.

```
for fn in os.listdir('.'):   # itterate through filenames in cwd
    f = open(fn,"rw+")       # make f a file object reading file name
    lines = f.readLines()    # Make an array of lines
    op = "---\n title:" +lines[0][2:]+"\n" #Assuming the title is the first line in the file.
    for k in lines[1:]:
        op += k + \n
    f.truncate()                            # Erase the old file
    f.write(op)                             # Write the file with the new title
    f.close()
```

While this will get the job done there are defiantly faster ways.

Comment: Thank you but as I'm not too familiar with python, I'm getting: line 6
    op += k + \n
               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character?