# Disable Apache (bulk) modpagespeed on shared hosting domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, plesk, mod-pagespeed

Maybe a stupid question, but this shouldn't be too hard to achieve :D
I have a shared server (CentOS - PLESK - Apache - PHP) and have ***modpagespeed*** enabled for just 1 domain. It all works, but every other domain is affected and a pain in the *** to disable.

I'm looking for a solution to manage / enable|disable this MOD for the hosted domains.
It would be a hard knock to go through every domains .htaccess file and set the **ModPagespeed off** for every instance :-(

Maybe I could serve 2 different .htaccess files in the future.. one with ModPagespeed on, and one with ModPagespeed off. If there's an easy way to bulk-edit the .htaccess files, I would like to know how ;-)

I hope someone out here has an answer for me! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you have all the pages on one machine ?

Comment: Correct. We have multiple servers, so if I enable modpagespeed, it affects all of the other domains that are hosted on the same server / machine, but not on the other servers of course. But if I enable modpagespeed for 1 domain on another server, the other domains on that server are affected also :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Your best solution of this is a script** that will modify (add or remove **ModPagespeed**) line from `.htaccess` file.

First though you'd have to add a line (either disable or enable) to every file/domain and then create a simple script that would seache for `.htaccess` files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` and modify the line in them.

For this task you can use `find` with `[sed][1]` of `[awk][1]`;

`find . -type f -name '.htaccess' -exec sed -i.bak 's|http://|rtmp://|g' {} +`

This is simply modified viersion of the one [you will find in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13364603/12257250).

If you run many servers (if it's a few then running a script manually on each of them shouldn't be a big deal) you can additionally make it to log in to every machine and make appropriate changes.

**Scripting is in my opinion the only way to achieve this in some reasonable easy way.**